# ES6 syntax destructuring object + implements interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm going through a code base and ran into complex syntax

```
return json?.result?.map(
({ text: label, value }: { text: string; value: any }) => ({
    label,
    value,
}),
);
```

I understand vaguely (correct me if I'm wrong) something like

For each result from the `json` object, run a function that takes in an object as a param and returns another object.

The param implements an interface with this `: { text: string; value: any }`

I don't understand what's going on here though `{ text: label, value }`. `label` is not a variable declared anywhere.

Comment: `label` is declared just like `value` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ text: label, value }` is a destructuring assignment and doesn't really have anything to do with typescript. It takes some object and binds its key 'value' to a local variable named value and its key 'text' to some local variable named 'label'.

For example:

```
const testObj = {
    text: "text",
    value: "value"
}

const printTestObj = ({ text: label, value }) => {
    console.log("label = " + label)
    console.log("value = " + value)
}

printTestObj(testObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is referred to as property renaming in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#property-renaming) and is an advanced form of object destructuring.

Your assessment of the structure of `json` is correct and it's type appears to be `Optional<{result?: {text: string, value: any}[]}>`. Thus the `ReturnType` of the function containing the above fragment is `Optional<{label: string, value: any}[]>`.